# Selenium remote webdriver doesn't accept desiredCapabilities

Tags: opera, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to launch a operaDriver using remoteWebdriver, and my code is:

```
static private IWebDriver driver;
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Opera();
driver = new RemoteWebDriver("http://localhost:9515", capability);
```

however this gives me error of RemoteDriver has invalid arguments, and it specifies RemoteDriver takes OpenQA.Selenium.ICapabilities type as argument, which is violated in my code.

I am confused here. Could anyone please share some lights?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this

It is as in java. You can try a URL class in C#

```
grid_url =  new URL("http://localhost:9515/wd/hub");
   driver = new RemoteWebDriver(grid_url, capability);
```